# Using optional arguments in a function to reverse a range python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, optional-arguments

I need to use an optional argument to take a range and reverse it by using a main function to call the function containing the arguments. My output needs to have the original range, followed by the same list in reverse. I cannot figure out how to put the reversal as an argument to get the output I need. I just end up with the range printed twice in sequential order. I have been playing around with this for hours so any help would be greatly appreciated. The reversal has to be done through the optional argument given to a_range so any answers saying not to do that won't help me.

Immediately below is how I am getting the range in sequential order:

```
def a_range(max, step):
  return list(range(0,max,step))

def main():
  result = a_range(55,2)
  print(result)

main()
```

Which gives me the output (sorry if formatting is wrong):

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 
40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54]
```

When I try to add a 3rd argument that reverses the same list:

```
def a_range(max, step, opt_arg = list(range(0,55,2))[::-1]):
    return list(range(0,max,step))
    return list(range(0,max,step,opt_arg)


def main():
    result = a_range(55,2)
    opt_arg = list(range(0,55,2))[::-1]
    print(result)
    other_result = a_range(55,2,opt_arg)
    print(other_result)


main()
```

I get the output:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 
40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38,  
42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54]
```

This is exactly how I need the output to be printed, but the 2nd repeat needs to be in reverse.

Comment: What is the `opt_arg` supposed to represent?  Is this function supposed to return the reversed range if that argument is `True`?

Comment: It's meant to reverse the list but only when called so that the function runs all the way through and prints the range in sequential order, then runs through the function again and prints it in reverse. I'm stuck because the reversal has to be done via optional argument.

Comment: @astute We need to see more example of input and output to be able to help you. Show us what the function should return given some inputs

Comment: @astute `other_result = a_range(55,2,opt_arg)[::-1]` will do that but I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code, the main one being that your optional argument should be a boolean flag.

Here is how you could implement it.

```
def prange(start, stop, step=1, reverse=False):
    fst = list(range(start, stop, step))
    if reverse:
        return (fst, list(reversed(fst)))
    else:
        return (fst,)

print(*prange(3, 6, reverse=True))
```

### Output

```
[3, 4, 5] [5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: I know the optional argument isn't necessary to make this happen; the catch is that I have to do it with an optional argument.

Comment: @astute What is *optional*? The optional argument must be triggering some change in the output, what is it?

Comment: I was trying to use opt_arg as an optional argument by setting it equal to the original list followed by [::-1] to reverse it. I'm very new to this so sometimes it is the most basic issue that I haven't learned about yet. I want to be able to call the optional argument after the original range has been printed so that I get the range in sequential order followed by the range in reverse as output.

Comment: No, the output should be: 

[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54]
[54, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 42, 40, 38, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]

Comment: @astute With what arguments? As you see my example does not provide the same arguments as yours, so of course the output is different. Please be clear: when you provide an output, also say which input led to it.

Comment: Someone suggested the same thing, so 30 minutes ago I updated the question to include my input and output.

Comment: @astute Is what you are saying that you need the output to be a list of list? What I am saying is that you need to be *way more* clear for us to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry I am trying...the output needs to be two ranges (so 2 separate lists, I suppose), both of them the same but the 2nd list should be the reverse of the 1st list. The output that I've written at the bottom of the question is exactly the way I need it to be with the only difference being that the 2nd instance of the list needs to be reversed.

Comment: @astute Does the new output makes sense to you?

Comment: Yes, thank you it is much appreciated! Is there a way to do the same thing but not have any parentheses?

Comment: @astute No, your output needs to be contained in some structure, here I used a tuple. If it is for printing purpose, you can do `print(*prange(3, 6, reverse=True))` though.  By the way, if the answer helped, please mark it as accepted so other users can find it more easily

Answer (score 0):

After a `return` you leave the function, additional returns do nothing.

You can append lists before returning:

```
def a_range(maxx, step, reverse = False):
    k = list(range(0,maxx,step))
    return k+k[::-1] if reverse else k


print(a_range(10,2))

print(a_range(10,2,True))
```

The last element of k occures twice if you set `reverse` to `True`:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this with the reversal happening within opt_arg (an optional argument) instead of making it happen in the function via k?

Comment: @astute Sure. Take in a boolean thats pre-set to `False`, only return the returned range if its `True`. Edited code.